# Mapping data from excel with Python

Tags: python, mapping, xlrd

I am reading data from an xls spreadsheet with xlrd. First, I gather the index for the column that contains the data that I need (may not always be in the same column in every instance):

```
amr_list, pssr_list, inservice_list = [], [], []
for i in range(sh.ncols):
    for j in range(sh.nrows):
        if 'amrprojectnumber' in sh.cell_value(j,i).lower():
            amr_list.append(sh.cell_value(j,i))
        if 'pssrnumber' in sh.cell_value(j,i).lower():
            pssr_list.append(sh.cell_value(j,i))
        if 'inservicedate' in sh.cell_value(j,i).lower():
            inservice_list.append(sh.cell_value(j,i))
```

Now I have three lists, which I need to use for writing data to a new workbook. The values in a row are related. So the index of an item in one list corresponds to the same index of the items in the other lists.

The `amr_list` has repeating string values. For example:

```
['4006BA','4006BA','4007AC','4007AC','4007AC']
```

The `pssr_list` always shares the same value as the `amr_list` but with additional info:

```
['4006BA(1)','4006BA(2)','4007AC(1)','4007AC(2)','4007AC(3)']
```

Finally, the `inservice_list` may or may not contain a variable date (as read from excel):

```
[40780.0, '', 40749.0, 40764.0, '']
```

This is the result I want from the data:

```
amr = { '4006BA':[('4006BA(1)',40780.0),('4006BA(2)','')], '4007AC':[('4007AC(1)',40749.0),('4007AC(2)',40764.0),('4007AC(3)','')] }
```

But I am having a hard time figuring out how an easy way to get there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look into itertools.groupby and

```
zip(amr_list, pssr_list, inservice_list)
```

For your case:

```
dict((x,list(a[1:] for a in y)) for x,y in
    itertools.groupby(zip(amr_list, pssr_list, inservice_list), lambda z: z[0]))
```

Note that this assumes your input is sorted by amr_list.

Another approach would be:

```
combined={}
for k, v in zip(amr_list, zip(pssr_list, inservice_list)):
    combined.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Which does not require your input to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help:

```
A = ['4006BA','4006BA','4007AC','4007AC','4007AC']
B = ['4006BA(1)','4006BA(2)','4007AC(1)','4007AC(2)','4007AC(3)']
C = [40780.0, '', 40749.0, 40764.0, '']

result = dict()
for item in xrange(len(A)):
    key = A[item]
    result.setdefault(key, [])
    result[key].append( (B[item], C[item] ) )

print result
```

This will print you the data in the format you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I see that this essentially does the same thing as @retracile 2nd example. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd example of @retracile is to much better than mine. If you are working with a huge amount of data, you can use "izip" instead of "zip". This will create a generator instead of compute all the list and in some cases it can be faster that "zip". The import is "from itertools import izip". Itertools is a nice package, take a look: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html